# Filling missing values of aspect (flat areas without data) using QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I calculated the aspects of point stations from a DEM and the flat areas are left without data (null). As the purpose of preparing aspect values is that I am going to do geostatistical analysis, missing observations of ASPECT are not allowed in the interpolation analysis as I think, I might be wrong.

Is there a way to fill in the missing ASPECT observations using QGIS?

Comment: Have you tried "Fill nodata"? Raster - Analysis

Comment: You had a tag for R but provided no code attempt so I’ve removed it and focused your question on QGIS.